# How is variance controlled in a matched random assignment?

Tags: variance, random-generation, matching

Can someone explain to me why in a matched random assignment, the variance is also controlled in addition to the mean? And if it doesn't control for the variance, is there a random assignment strategy such that the mean and variance between groups is the same?

To illustrate: say there's a drug trial testing the efficacy of a weight-loss drug. A placebo and the drug is given to 1) a population with a known genetic predisposition for weight gain 2) people without this pre-disposition, but who eat a similar diet. How do we divy up the individuals so that the mean and variance are the same in all 4 groups?

Comment: "Mean and variance" of what, exactly?  What would the purpose be of making these statistics the same in each group?  Could you explain what you mean by "controlling" for variance?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the lack of clarity. Mean and variance of my experimental groups. It is easy to make assignments into the groups so that the mean of each group is nearly equivalent, but how would assignments work such that the spread within each group is equal to each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "mean" and "variance"? I assume - talking about the clinical trial example - not the mean (and variance) of the post-treatment outcomes on the two treatment groups (presumably different in expectation, if treatments are differently effective), but e.g. baseline covariates? One way ensuring a baseline covariate balance is adaptive randomization, but this may also complicate the analysis.

Comment: @Björn Yes, you are right that I was referring to baseline covariates - to stretch the same example, I would want to make sure the weight of all of my participants are roughly the same to begin with if I want to make a convincing argument further down the study.